# Creating a JSON Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to create this JSON array in PHP. If I `echo` this:

```
{"SUCCESS":[{"message":"Your Accout Info","AccoutInfo":{"credit":"$56.98USD","mail":"mail@me.com","currency":"USD"}}],"apiversion":"2.3.1"}
```

The echo code above works as I want.

---

The code below building a array doesn't work:

```
    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    $data[SUCCESS] = array(
        'credit'   => '$56.98USD',
        'mail' => 'mail@me.com',
        'message' => 'Your Accout Info',
        'currency' => 'USD',
        'apiversion' => '2.3.1'  
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks

---

**UPDATE:**

I have updated my code to this:

```
    $data = array('SUCCESS' => array(
        'message'   => 'Your Accout Info',
        'AccoutInfo' => array(
        'credit' => '$56.98USD',
        'mail' => 'me@mail.com',
        'currency' => 'USD'),
        'apiversion' => '2.3.1')
   );
```

And now I get this result:

```
{"SUCCESS":{"message":"Your Accout Info","AccoutInfo":{"credit":"$56.98USD","mail":"me@mail.com","currency":"USD"},"apiversion":"2.3.1"}}
```

But I need this result:

```
{"SUCCESS":[{"message":"Your Accout Info","AccoutInfo":{"credit":"$56.98USD","mail":"me@mail.com","currency":"USD"}}],"apiversion":"2.3.1"}
```

Any advice to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 $data[SUCCESS] = array(...
```

to

```
 $data["SUCCESS"] = array(
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create `$data`, it can be an object or an array and use `SUCCESS` as a string `'SUCCESS'` rather than an undefined constant.

```
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
$data = array('SUCCESS' => array(
        array(
            'AccoutInfo' => array(
                'credit'   => '$56.98USD',
                'mail' => 'mail@me.com',
                'currency' => 'USD'
            ),
            'message' => 'Your Accout Info',
        )
    ),
    'apiversion' => '2.3.1'  
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

also the json you hard code and the structure you try to build is very different

Comment: Didnt work, looks like "AccoutInfo" is a array inside array again?

Comment: Its reporting error on line 12. Anyway I got it working in my answer below. Thank you for your help. It helped me to make this array successfull. Check  below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
$data = array('SUCCESS' => array(
        'credit'   => '$56.98USD',
        'mail' => 'mail@me.com',
        'message' => 'Your Accout Info',
        'currency' => 'USD',
        'apiversion' => '2.3.1'  
    )
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working :-)

```
<?php
    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    $data = Array
    (
        'SUCCESS' => Array
            (
                '0' => Array
                    (
                        'message' => 'Your Accout Info',
                        'AccoutInfo' => Array
                            (
                                'credit' => '$56.98USD',
                                'mail' => 'me@mail.com',
                                'currency' => 'USD'
                            )
                    )
            ),
        'apiversion' => '2.3.1'
        );

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Thanks to @Musa who pointed me in right direction.